# Create Pivot table for Multiple Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, pivot-table

I need VBA script to create pivot table in same sheet for each worksheet in a workbook, can I get a help on this i had tried so many but error or upon.

I had tried so many scripts regarding this but every time run a errors are endless

```vb
Sub Ptloop()

dim x as long
dim SorceRange as Range
dim k as long
'start of first generated work sheet
x=4
'number of worksheets
k=75


Set SourceRange = Range("A4", ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If x <= k Then

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
   Sheets(x).SourceRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Sheets(x).Cells(4, 21), TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
   :=xlPivotTableVersion14
 x = x + 1
Else
Exit For
End If
Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help (and less likely to have your question closed) if you post some actual code you tried and describe what happened when you ran it.

Comment: kindly check the code i used i get syntax error and typemismatch error

Comment: You're creating all these pivots from the same source data?

Comment: no each sheet has their own data, but the data range is same

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: yes but the src data range shoes an error...

Comment: "an error" is not very descriptive - what is the exact error and on which line?  Added an update using your posted `SourceRange` method...

Comment: instead i recorded a macro and made changes it worked properly while I check by pressing f8 but cannot loopit automatically

Answer (score 0):

This should be close:

```vb
Sub Ptloop()

    Dim x As Long, pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable, wb As Workbook
    Dim sourceData As Range
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For x = 4 To 75
        With wb.Worksheets(x)
            'Set sourceData = .Range("A4").CurrentRegion
            Set sourceData = .Range("A4", _
                                    .Range("A4").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
            
            Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                        sourceData:=sourceData, _
                        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
            Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=.Cells(4, 21), _
                       TableName:="PivotTable3", _
                       DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```